# unordered list with image background, make it the same height if 1 or 2 lines

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm trying to have an unordered list with a background image as bullets. The image is 80px in height so I defined the inline height to 80x. The problem is that some of my bullets are too long and go to a second line. I want to make this second line fit in the original 80px. How would I do this so that I have some bullets with 1 lines that are centered vertically with the bullet image, and some bullets that are 2 lines and also centered vertically with the image, each bullet row would be 80px exactly no matter the amount of lines.

Here's my current code:

```
<ul id="star-wars">
      <li id="one">blablabla</li>
      <li id="two">blablavla</li>
</ul>


#star-wars
{
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    list-style-position:inside;
}

#star-wars li
{
    background-image: url(images/star-wars-icons/Han-Solo-02-icon.png);
        padding-left: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just forgetting to set the height value to your list.

```
#star-wars li {
    height:80px;
}
```

Comment: if I do that, both lines are being written over each other, if I add it and remove inline height, it does work, but then my text isn't centered vertically with the background image anymore. If you can suggest a way to center it without the inline height that would work perfectly